# $\frac{4}{x}<\:4<\frac{12}{x}\:\Leftrightarrow \frac{x}{12}<\: \frac{1}{4}<\frac{x}{4}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Could someone help me with this question?
Is this equivalence correct? When we alternate the numerator by the denominator, do we reverse the signal and what is between the unequal permace equal or also alternate?

$\frac{4}{x}<\:4<\frac{12}{x}\:\Leftrightarrow \frac{x}{12}<\: \frac{1}{4}<\frac{x}{4}$

Comment: try with $ x=2$

Comment: Use $4 < 12/x$ to get $x>0$.  For the **positive** case, $a<b$ implies $1/a > 1/b$.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you get from one inequality to the other. Please clarify, Fernando.

Comment: Next time, please avoid  titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: @soupless Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just have to keep in mind that multiplying and dividing by a positive number, the inequality is not altered. So:
\begin{align*}
\frac{4}{x}  &< 4           \\
\frac{4x}{4x}&< \frac{4x}{4}\\
\frac{4}{4}  &< \frac{4x}{4}\\
1            &< x           \\
\frac{1}{4}  &< \frac{x}{4}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
4                   &< \frac{12}{x}          \\
\frac{4x}{12}       &< \frac{12x}{12x}       \\
\frac{4x}{12\times4}&< \frac{12x}{12x\times4}\\
\frac{x}{12}        &< \frac{1}{4}           
\end{align*}
Then:
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{12} < \frac{1}{4} < \frac{x}{4}.
\end{align*}
For $x>0$.